# Как изменить запрос, что бы

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос в Oracle

```
select krt_log
from   t_trm_log, 
       (select to_date('YYYYMMDD')a from dual) dl
where  tm>decode(dl.a, to_date('20150203', 'YYYYMMDD'), trunc(sysdate, 'DD'), dl.a)
order  by id desc
```

Данный запрос используется для формирования отчёта, требуется его модифицировать что бы не вводить дату в формате `20150203`, а писать кол-во дней, например за 10 дней и что бы большее кол-во дней уже было не доступно. 
Кто подскажет, заранее спасибо.

Comment: что такое `tm`? и 10 дней от чего? от текущего времени?

Comment: Во первых подзапрос совершенно не нужен, тот в  котором не хватает параметра у to_date. А количество дней до какой то даты получается просто вычитанием дат. т.е. что то типа `sysdate - tm` (при условии что tm типа данных date)

Answer (score 0):

Если tm это столбец таблицы t_trm_log, то написав запрос следующим образом, всегда будет выводит отчет за последние 10 дней.

```
select krt_log
from   t_trm_log t
where  t.tm between trunc(sysdate - 10) and trunc(sysdate)
```